# ffmpeg default filter for input sources

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to create a video from a bunch of still images (as [described on the ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)) but I'd like to do a cross fade between each image. Is there any way to do this short of dynamically generating a gigantic filter string with filters for each pair of images?

Comment: Are you fading out to a single color before fading back in? or is this a cross-fade between the two images? The process might be to create the videos for each piece, fade in and out for each piece, then concat them all together. Cross-fade may be easier with video editing tool (I don't know).

Comment: cross fade between subsequent images

Comment: Microsoft Movie Maker has this functionality.